# Assign rows and column values to a NaN matrix in specific locations

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a NaN (155*135) matrix, and another matrix showing a specific value with row and column numbers. Is there a way that I can assign these values back to the NaN matrix eventually having the same location and everything else remaining as NaN?

```
R   C  Value
19  4  -1133.803
20  4  -295.6810
32  4  -1906.021
20  5  -1027.048
21  5  -293.0065
32  5   236.0525
33  5  -425.1248
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sub2ind`:

```
data = [
  % R   C   Value
    19  4  -1133.803
    20  4  -295.6810
    32  4  -1906.021
    20  5  -1027.048
    21  5  -293.0065
    32  5   236.0525
    33  5  -425.1248];
N = nan(155,135);
N(sub2ind(size(N),data(:,1),data(:,2))) = data(:,3);
```

So you get for `N(min(data(:,1)):max(data(:,1)),min(data(:,2)):max(data(:,2)))` (i.e. `N(19:32,4:5)`):

```
ans =
      -1133.8          NaN
      -295.68        -1027
          NaN      -293.01
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
        -1906       236.05
          NaN      -425.12
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
result = accumarray([R C] , Value,[155,135],[],NaN)
```

Note: `R` and `C` assumed to be column vectors

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Although I have like 1675 values to write.